# Add column of radio buttons in extendedDataTable in RichFaces

Tags: richfaces

My goal is to add the a first column of an `extendedDataTable` which has one radio button for each row.  The user can then selects the row they want to perform an action on. I'm unable to find a way to implement it in the table definition or a way to create a rich column individually to hold the radio buttons.  Any advice?  Here is the table definition code.

```
<rich:extendedDataTable 
    style="width: 800px; height: 150px;" 
    rowClasses="Row0,Row1" 
    value="#{value}" 
    var="exception" 
    selectionMode="single" 
    id="Table" 
    selection="#{selection}"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<rich:extendedDataTable value="#{projectCreation.creationModel.resourceModelList}"
                            var="availableResource" id="availableResourceTable" 
                            selectionMode="none" noDataLabel="Record not found" >
                    <rich:column>
                       <f:facet name="header" >
                            <h:outputText value="select"/>
                        </f:facet>

                         <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{availableResource.selected}">
                            <f:ajax/>
                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>                 

                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column >
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Employee Id"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{availableResource.employeeId}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column id="employeeName">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Employee Name"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{availableResource.employeeName}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Group"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{availableResource.group}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Start Date"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{availableResource.startDate}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="End Date"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{availableResource.endDate}"/>
                    </rich:column>


                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Loading"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{availableResource.loading}"/>
                    </rich:column>

                </rich:extendedDataTable>
```